# How to get the id name of the Node?

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I have a `div` tag as follows:

```
<div id="DataEntryForm" style="position:absolute; left:100px;top:175px;width:350px;  z-index:2;background-color:yellow; visibility:hidden;border-top-color: black;">
    <table id="DataEntryFormTable" style=" width:100%" style="margin-top: -50px;">
        <tr><td>&nbsp;Build Name</td><td> <input type="text" id="BuildName" name="BuildName" value="" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;Build Description</td><td> <input type="text" id="BuildDesc" name="BuildDesc" value="" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;Software Details</td><td> <input type="text" id="SoftwareDetail" name="SoftwareDetail" value="" /> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;Hardware Details</td><td> <input type="text" id="HardwareDetail" name="HardwareDetail" value="" /> </td></tr><br>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveRecord()" /></td>
            <td> <input type="button" value="Cancel"  onclick="cancelOperation()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <br>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to load the values from the database to the input type text. So, I need to get the id of each node in order to match with my json value and node id and to assign the value to it. I'm trying with the following to achieve this. But, I cannot get the id value. Anyone, please help me out on this. Thanks ..

```
var nodes = deform.childNodes;
index =0;

// Load the first record in the collection.
// It is expected to have only one object in JS Object collection
var dbRecord= dbRecords[0];

while (index < nodes.length)
{
    if(nodes[index].type=="text")
    {
        nodes[index].value = dbRecord[nodes[index].id];
    }

    index++;
}
```

Comment: can you show us a live example or at least the content of `dbRecord` ?

Comment: THis is the dbRecord Content-- [{"HardwareDetail":"[B","BuildDesc":"Testing1","BuildID":"BL002","BuildName":"Second Name","SoftwareDetail":"ss"}]

Comment: You may want to use a for loop instead. Or say `while (index++ < nodes.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is the correct property.  the problem is that you are not retrieving the nodes that you are trying to retrieve from your table.  Using .children() or .childNodes(), only gets direct children of your element, so you need to drill down further into your table to access the text inputs your are trying to fill.  Alternatively, if you want to use jQuery, a single selector could do the trick:

`$("#DataEntryFormTable input[type='text']")`

If you don't use jQuery, I would use .children() recursively to find the elements you're looking for.

edit:  Also, make sure you include parenthesis when calling a function, so
`var nodes = deform.childNodes;`
 would be 
`var nodes = deform.childNodes();`

edit again:
... I didn't see the data that you provided.  since you have the ID's that you need in your JSON data, you can look up the elements directly using those ids.  Try this:

```
dbRecord= [{"HardwareDetail":"[B","BuildDesc":"Testing1","BuildID":"BL002","BuildName":"Se­cond Name","SoftwareDetail":"ss"}];
record = dbRecord[0];
for (attr in record){
    el = document.getElementById(attr);
    if (el)
        document.getElementById(attr).value = record[attr];
    else
        console.debug('no HTML element with ID ' + attr);
}
```

I don't think `console.debug` works in some browsers (IE?), so you'll want to take that part out when you're finished testing.

Comment: This loop is infinite. I cannot execute those code. How to break this loop. Why it is infinite?

Comment: it shouldn't be infinite, but your dbRecord contains an object inside an array, and I wrote my code as if the array was not there, or as if the data you posted was dbRecords, not dbRecord.  You might need to access the first element of the array before iterating over the attributes.  I'll update the code to clarify.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now I got it. The reason being is nodes index loop is still there. That is why the loop gone infinite. Now it is working.